# Is unset useful?

Tags: php

I never ever saw someone using `unset` and I was wondering if that saves something or if it is a completely waste of time and code?

```
<?php
$message = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3";
mail('admin@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);

/* IS THERE ANY REASON TO UNSET $message ? */
unset($message);
?>
```

Comment: Are you asking whether it's useful *in your example* or *at all*?

Comment: this is as simple as reading the man page ... it tells you what the `unset` function does. so if you ever need to do what `unset` does, use it. if you don't, then don't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It depends.**

If you're developing a long-running daemon or job, `unset()` can be used to keep memory in reasonable bounds: to help prevent leaks.

If you're developing a page/script for a web application, `unset()` isn't terribly useful for memory management.

And in *either* case, it's useful if you're relying on `array`s and you need to remove a value. A silly example, perhaps ... but consider something like this:

```
$users = getUsers($someCondition);
foreach ($users as $k => $v) {
  unset($users[$k]['password_hash']);
}
print json_encode($users);
```

In the specific example you've given, it's useless:

```
<?php
$message = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3";
mail('admin@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);

// PHP is about to clean everything up anyway ... don't bother doing this:
unset($message);
?>
```

Comment: Your example is theoretically valid, but I've found that PHP often does not like it when you modify the current index in a foreach loop.

Comment: @Sammitch Yeah. I'm not sure that concern applies to this example, since I'm not removing or adding anything from/to the collection being iterated over. But, if my example *does* cause issues, it hopefully still illustrates the potential use-case for `unset()` in a web environment.

Comment: I just remembered, it was `unset($users[$k]);` that PHP didn't like. IIRC when you do that the array's internal pointer goes all wonky.

Comment: @Sammitch Yep! That's the one! ... Any sort of splicing and dicing will cause problems. PHP isn't the only language that won't tolerate it. C# also throws an exception if the iterated-over collection is changed. Javascript doesn't complain; but it skips items!

Answer (score 5):

When passing the foreach `$value` by reference, `$value` is still in scope after the loop has completed. Stop that madness with [`unset()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php).

```
foreach($array as &$value)
{
    $value = "something else"
}

var_dump($value);
// string(5) "thing"

unset($value);
var_dump($value);
// Notice: Undefined variable: value
```

Answer (score 4):

There is hardly a reason to do so. All memory will be freed when the script terminates.

But, if you allocate a lot of memory it might be useful to do so, especially if your scripts take a little longer to run. The memory will be freed immediately and can be used by other scripts.

But like you say, it takes code to do so, making your code less clear. So only do this if you have allocated large chunks of data that you don't longer need, like file contents read from disk or big arrays with query results. Don't go freeing integers and don't worry about your message string either. :)

{edit after comments}

My answer was mainly focused to using PHP for website scripting. Of course if you are creating long running scripts, especially if the amount of memory they allocate is very variable, then of course it can make sense to free up memory, although even those scripts run for a limited period of time.

I don't think there are many daemons written in PHP that run forever. Most scripts, even those shell scripts, perform a specific task (if you can call 'rendering a website' or 'migrating a database' specific) after which they end. Within the context of that task it is still quite useless to free up every variable you allocated. This is a big different between scripts like this and programs that might run for a long time, perform the same task over and over again or are completely user-controlled, so you don't know what they will do. And if you do manage to write a long running script or daemon in PHP, other rules apply, because it's another kind of application. But by that time, you won't be searching this answer, because you have gained more than enough knowledge already to know what you're doing.

Comment: It's good when you want to be defensive. For example, `if (cond) $var = true;` then later... `if (isset($var)) doSomething();`... In this case, `$var` *might* have been set by an earlier script, perhaps like `foreach ($item as $var)`.

Comment: In that case your variables name are not enough explicit... If you do an isset on something which might be initialized 100 lines before for another thing, it's weird.

Comment: I retract my statement because I don't have time (or space) to flesh out what I'm talking about. So, nevermind. In the OP's case I don't think it will be a consideration anyways, but obviously there are uses for `unset()` - just not in the OP's example.

Comment: Even though it might seem inpractical to others to write daemon code or long running shell scripts with PHP, this is possible and i've seen some. In this context, freeing up memory (i.e. during a loop) totally makes sense!

Comment: I WAS WONDERING IF THERE IS A QUICK FAST METHOD TO CLEAR ALL VARIABLES IN MEMORY INSTEAD OF GOING TO UNSET($A,$B,$C); etc... IS THERE ANY COMMAND TO SHRED ALL VARIABLES AND CLEAN FREE MEMORY ?

Comment: Regarding "makes code less clear" i also have a different opinion: explicitly writing that the variable will no longer be used after `unset()` is a good thing.

Comment: @AdwardSmith Turn off the caps lock please

Comment: @Kaii It is possible, and cleaning up does make sense in that case. But it is the exception to the rule. It seems to me that is will be some time before OP will start writing PHP daemons. I've added a paragraph to my answer as well.

Answer (score 4):

Especially useful for arrays. I've allways used it to remove array elements I no longer needed.

```
$arr = array('test', 'No longer needed');

unset($arr[1]);
```

But I personally don't think it's useful in your code example.

Answer (score 3):

One use for unset is for limiting the scope of the variable.

```
<?php
$message = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3";
mail('admin@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);

/* if you don't unset $message here, it will span across the include below */
unset($message);

include 'library.inc.php';
?>
```

From the php manual:

> The scope of a variable is the context within which it is defined. For
>   the most part all PHP variables only have a single scope. This single
>   scope spans included and required files as well. For example:

You can read more about variable scopes here:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Ideally, variables should be initialized properly, but if you wan't to be completely sure that you don't introduce side-effects to the included file, just unset your variable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it fits here, but I've used unset() with $_SESSION variables...

I believe I was using it for passing error messages through the pages. When the error is echoed or dealt with - `unset($_SESSION['error'])` would clear the error message and the script could continue.